# SQL Trigger to Insert a row

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm using postgresql. These are the table involved in the trigger:

Pricing (title,publisher,period,offer,price)

- The DB has 4 tables describing a magazine business.
- The table above shows the title, publisher of the magazine, period (an option the subscribe to the magazine, in months (integer), offer (a string, like 'regular' or 'renew'), and price (integer).

The question:

```
Write a trigger that adds a new row in the pricing table. 
If a new row is inserted with offer='regular', insert a new row, exactly the same BUT:
offer='renew' and a price discount of 10%.
```

Here my trigger, which doesn't work:

```
create or replace function offer_f() returns trigger as $$

begin  
    if(TG_OP='insert') then
        if new.offer='regular' then
            insert into pricing (title,pusblisher,offer,period, price)
            values (new.title,new.publisher,"renew",new.period,new.price*0.9);
        end if;
    end if;
return new;

end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

This is the trigger itself:

```
create trigger reduced_offer
after insert or update on pricing
for each row
execute procedure offer_f()
```

I really don't know what's wrong here, and I have tried replacing "after" with "before" in the trigger.

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: First, why would you be creating an `update` trigger, given that requirement?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? What behavior are you seeing here?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have another part of the question where I have to update a row, but I am starting with the first part.

Comment: @Mureinik - Well, nothing happens. If I add a row, it is added to the table, but the trigger doesn't add another row (the 'renew' row).

Comment: @Mureinik I wish I could be more specific but I couldn't find a way to install a debugger in PostgreSQL.

Comment: `"renew"` -->> `'renew'` Single quotes for literals. And you don't need the VALUES() here, just the values+literals will do.

Comment: @wildplasser thanks, but it didn't help. I did change the values syntax.

Comment: BTW to debug plpgsql code [messages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) can be used. In your case try `raise info '%', new;` Of course the client application should be able to catch those messages (psql, pgAdmin,...)

Comment: `"renew"` is a column reference, not a string constant.